# Icon Font not displaying properly in web application

Tags: javascript, html, icons, font-awesome

I am using font awesome but some of the icons are not displaying properly.

[image: screenshot]

Please help me with this. What is the possible reason for this type of error

Comment: HTML? CSS? PYTHON? You haven't mentioned any coding languages, nor have you included them as tags.

Comment: It is in HTML and java script